# Double file extensions

Tags: javascript, operating-system, file-extension

## Musings

I have seen in linux sometimes `.tar.gz` meaning it is a tar file that has been gzipped. does the system ignore the `.tar` part until it has been unzipped? Are there other use cases of this?

In web development, we often use double extensions for our script files `jquery.min.js`. Is there a standard or cohesive logic to this? Can I use `jquery.my-library.coffee.min.packed.js.gz` to indicate it is originally coffee-script, that has been compiled to javascript, minified, packed and finally zipped.

It would be very useful if we could add some meaning to double extensions, like `README.md.txt`, so that if we are looking on a system which does not know what markdown is, it will fallback to txt and display with a text editor. If the system knows markdown, it will open with a markdown editor. This would work kind of like a mime type.

## Questions

1. What situations are double file extensions currently used by operating systems or programming languages?
2. Is it possible to extend the use of double file extensions with existing os/language packages?
3. What conventions are there for use of double file extensions?

Comment: I searched for "double file extensions" to see if there was somewhere I could post my idea for fallback extensions like `readme.md.txt` or `readme.rst.txt`.  Someone else had the same idea, apparently.  :D

Comment: what is `rst` extension?

Comment: reStructuredText, similar to markdown

Comment: Hey, they already exist and are understood by github! https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/EXAMPLE_DOCSTRING.rst.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File extensions are nothing more than a residue from the good ol' DOS days. Mac OS don't use them for anything more than Windows interop issues. Mac OS uses something similar to substreams to store content type. When you download a file from the internet on a Mac, the content type from the HTTP headers are interpreted - not the filename.

Windows still uses filename extensions, unfortunately.

The most important thing on the web is serving the proper `Content-Type`! And, as @thenetimp says, it's the rightmost part that counts in Windows.

Comment: Interesting answer. I did not know that about OSX.

Comment: Mime-Type guessing can be a mess, so there is definitely a use case for file extensions. Magic numbers are far less reliable. Think of all the text based formats.

Comment: That is why mime types should never be guessed, but provided by the party that knows the type. Mime types are traditionally much more expressive than filename extensions.

Comment: I'm using macOS, and though my HTTP header Content-Type says 'text/plain', my mac asks me every time what app to use when there's a weird filename extension. But when it's .txt then mac opens it with the default text editor as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The extension to the far right i considered the extension of the file.  Therefore .gz is a gzip file.  query.myplugin.js is a javascript file. etc...